# Windows 10 - F2 won't rename a file - opens Excel instead

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I got a computer (Dell Precision) with Windows 10 and the f2 opens an excel and does not rename files.

To change this I tried:

- Reset BIOS settings
- Change the keyboard mapping to defaults using the Regedit
- Looked up for Excel shortcut in the properties windows of it

Nothing helped - what can I do next?

Comment: Did you try Fn/F2 ? Often machines have regular F-Keys vs 'smart functions' which can be toggled in system prefs or by holding Fn.

Comment: nope didnt work - Fn + F2 changes the volume

Comment: F2 (plain F2) from Windows does not normally open Excel. Did you change the function in a prior computer?

Comment: @John I got the computer in this state - i guess they did something to it. But they are not reachable to me anymore

Comment: Yes, the state you got it in is not normal.  You (or someone you know) can do a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link.  That may fix the computer.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Is there an F LOCK key? If so, try pressing that to toggle its state.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: I just discovered that WIN+f2 does the rename stuff. I'ts good enough but still i would prefer just the f2.

Comment: Did the F2 key ever function normally?

Comment: Laptops come standard with `F` keys doing things like brightness and volume. You press `Fn` key to activate them as `F` keys. Look at the labels on the `F` keys.

Comment: where  in windows 10 do i control this kind of stuff? say f2 works normally - where do i change it to open excel?

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Answer (score 1):

Windows allows shortcut keys to be assigned to programs via their shortcut icons. It sounds like this is probably what happened in your case with the <kbd>F2</kbd> key.

Look on your desktop for a shortcut to excel and open it's properties.  Check the **Shortcut Key** text box and see if it says <kbd>F2</kbd>, such as in the example below.

[image: Shortcut properties]

If so, focus the shortcut key field and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> to remove the assignment so the box says *None* then click <kbd>OK</kbd>.